# Until which depth can aptitude -v verbose work?

Tags: debian, aptitude

I have tried to understand how the verbose flag works and failed. Both the man page and the [aptitude reference guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02.html).

The only helping usage is given at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s05.en.html#configCmdLine-Verbose:

> **Option:** `Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose`
>     **Default:** `0`
>     **Description:**
>   This controls how verbose the command-line mode of **aptitude** is. 
>   Every occurrence of the `-v` command-line option adds 1 to this value.

But it doesn't inform us until which range this works. Also it doesn't tell if you use

```
~$ cat ~/.aptitude/config
Verbose "2";
```

then is doing `aptitude -v` useless or not?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it's a breadcrumb. https://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/aptitude lets you download the source code. It appears each -v simply increments a "verbose" variable, which is then passed on to subsequent commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer your question is, as Jeff Schaller, said to look at the source code. You can get the last version with:

```
git clone https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/aptitude/aptitude.git
```

and then look at the occurence of the `verbose` string.

```
cd aptitude/src
grep -R verbose *
```

You obtain the following output:

```
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:              int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                      verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                      verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:           int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:            if(verbose>0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:            if(verbose>0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:  if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:  if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:    if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:  if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:  if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:    if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:        if (verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                    verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:           int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                                   verbose, source,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                      verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:               verbose, source,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                verbose, source,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:            int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.cc:                    verbose, policy,
cmdline/cmdline_simulate.cc:             bool always_prompt, int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_simulate.cc:            always_prompt, verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_simulate.cc:  if(verbose==0)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:                       int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:static void show_package(pkgCache::PkgIterator pkg, int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:  fragments.push_back(prv_lst_frag(pkg.ProvidesList(), true, verbose, _("Provided by")));
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:                    int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:  if (verbose>0)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      if(verbose<2) // Show all archives in a list.
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:  fragments.push_back(prv_lst_frag(ver.ProvidesList(), false, verbose, _("Provides")));
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:  fragments.push_back(prv_lst_frag(ver.ParentPkg().ProvidesList(), true, verbose, _("Provided by")));
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:static void show_version(pkgCache::VerIterator ver, int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      cw::fragment *f=version_file_fragment(ver, ver.FileList(), verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      cw::fragment *f=version_file_fragment(ver, vf, verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      // If verbose<2, only show the first file.
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      if(verbose<2)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:                int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:  if(verbose == 0 || has_explicit_source)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:    show_version(ver, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:    show_package(pkg, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:      show_version(ver, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:    show_package(pkg, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:bool do_cmdline_show(const string& s, int verbose, const std::shared_ptr<terminal_metrics> &term_metrics)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:                                  verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:                                     verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:int cmdline_show(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_show.cc:    if(!do_cmdline_show(argv[i], verbose, term))
cmdline/cmdline_moo.cc:int cmdline_moo(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_moo.cc:  switch(verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_moo.h:int cmdline_moo(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_why.h:     *  \param verbosity  How verbose the search should be (if set to a value
cmdline/cmdline_util.h: *  \param verbose  the verbosity level; controls how many
cmdline/cmdline_util.h:                      int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:            int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:    if (operation_result && verbose>0)
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:               int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:    print_result(act, tag, pkg, verbose, op_result);
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:    int cmdline_user_tag(int argc, char *argv[], int quiet, int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:          bool result = do_user_tag(action, tag, pkg, verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.cc:              bool result = do_user_tag(action, tag, pkg, verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.h:              int verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_update.cc:int cmdline_update(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_update.cc:    (cmdline_do_download(&m, verbose, term, term, term, term)
cmdline/cmdline_util.cc:                         int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_util.cc:            verbose >= 1, verbose >= 2,
cmdline/cmdline_show.h: *  \param verbose  How much information to render (scale of 0 to 2 inclusive).
cmdline/cmdline_show.h:                  int verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_show.h:          int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_show.h:int cmdline_show(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_action.h: *  \param verbose The verbosity level at which this command should
cmdline/cmdline_action.h:            int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.h: *  \param verbose The verbosity level at which this command should
cmdline/cmdline_action.h:            int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_action.h: *  \param verbose The verbosity level at which this command should
cmdline/cmdline_action.h:             int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:             bool queue_only, int verbose)
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:                            verbose, policy, arch_only, pass > 0,
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:      if(!aptitude::cmdline::safe_resolve_deps(verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:               always_prompt, verbose, assume_yes,
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:               always_prompt, verbose, assume_yes,
cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc:   (cmdline_do_download(&m, verbose, term, term, term, term)
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:             int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:      make_cmdline_why_callbacks(verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:    if(verbose > 1)
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:    else if(verbose > 0)
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc: *  \param verbose controls various aspects of how verbose the list is.
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:    std::string whystring(roots_string(*i, verbose, term_metrics));
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:            int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:              verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:      cmdline_show_instinfo(recommended, verbose, showvers, showdeps, showsize, false, showwhy, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:  if(verbose>0 && !suggested.empty())
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:      cmdline_show_instinfo(suggested, verbose, showvers, showdeps, showsize, false, showwhy, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:  if (verbose>0 && ! not_upgraded.empty())
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:      cmdline_show_instinfo(not_upgraded, verbose, showvers, showdeps, showsize, false, showwhy, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                 int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:      do_cmdline_show(*it, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:             int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                 showvers, showdeps, showsize, showwhy, verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                    verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                     verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:        cmdline_parse_show(response, verbose, term_metrics);
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.cc:                   to_remove, to_purge, verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_user_tag.h:    int cmdline_user_tag(int argc, char *argv[], int quiet, int verbose);
cmdline/cmdline_simulate.h: *  \param verbose the current verbosity level
cmdline/cmdline_simulate.h:          bool always_prompt, int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.h: *  \param verbose the current verbosity level
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.h:              int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_prompt.h:             int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.h: *  \param verbose the verbosity level set by the user
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.h:          int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.h:     *  \param verbose   The verbosity level (increase to get more
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.h:    bool safe_resolve_deps(int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.cc:             int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.cc:                       to_remove, to_purge, verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_resolver.cc:    bool safe_resolve_deps(int verbose,
cmdline/cmdline_update.h:int cmdline_update(int argc, char *argv[], int verbose);
main.cc:  {"verbose", 0, NULL, 'v'},
main.cc:  int verbose=aptcfg->FindI(PACKAGE "::CmdLine::Verbose", 0);
main.cc:      ++verbose;
main.cc:        return cmdline_update(argc-optind, argv+optind, verbose);
main.cc:                   status_fname, verbose,
main.cc:                   status_fname, verbose,
main.cc:                       arch_only, queue_only, verbose);
main.cc:                               quiet, verbose);
main.cc:        return cmdline_moo(argc-optind, argv+optind, verbose);
main.cc:        return cmdline_show(argc-optind, argv+optind, verbose);
```

We see that the verbose variable is incremented in main.cc:

```
// Read the arguments:
  while((curopt=getopt_long(argc, argv, "DVZWvhS:uiF:w:sO:fdyPt:q::Rro:", opts, NULL))!=-1)
    {
      switch(curopt)
        {
             //Other options

             case 'v':
               ++verbose;
               break;

             //Other options
```

It means that each times a `v` appears in the options from the command line `verbose` is incremented by 1. But the maximum litteral value against which `verbose` is tested is `2` in `verbose>=2`. **It means than having more than `-vv` in the command line is useless.**

## Edit

More directly, we see in cmdline_show.h

```
*  \param verbose  How much information to render (scale of 0 to 2 inclusive).
```