# Verbosity in aptitude command-line mode via its configuration file

Tags: debian, apt, configuration, aptitude

This is related to a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235667/till-what-depth-can-aptitude-v-verbose-work) I asked about 3 years ago. Since then things have changed a bit apparently. One of the obvious ones is that aptitude itself has changed from whatever version it was to aptitude  0.8.12 or to be more precise -

```
$ aptitude --version
aptitude 0.8.12
Compiler: g++ 9.2.1 20190821
Compiled against:
  apt version 5.0.2
  NCurses version 6.1
  libsigc++ version: 2.10.1
  Gtk+ support disabled.
  Qt support disabled.

Current library versions:
  NCurses version: ncurses 6.1.20191019
  cwidget version: 0.5.18
  Apt version: 5.0.2
```

The other thing which has changed is aptitude has its documentation in aptitude-doc-en and the point/documentation I am interested is located in -

file:///usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/ch02s05s05.html

where it says -

> ```
> Option: Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose
> Default: 0
> Description: This controls how verbose the command-line mode of aptitude is. Every occurrence of the -v command-line option adds 1 to
> ```
>
> this value.

Now the configuration file is supposed to be in one of the three places and I chose and made a 3-4  lines at

```
$ cat ~/.aptitude/config
Aptitude "";
Aptitude::CmdLine "";
Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose "2";
```

Now I don't know if this is good enough or not. I tried the following commands -

```
$ sudo apt update
```

and

```
$ sudo aptitude update
```

But neither gave me any more output. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the verbosity setting, your configuration is correct (but you only need the last line). However, `apt update` doesn’t use Aptitude’s settings, so you won’t see a difference there. The difference with `aptitude update` is minor, it adds a status line at the end, showing the number of upgradable packages etc.

To check verbosity settings, the best command is `aptitude moo`: it shows a different message for each verbosity setting up to 6.

Comment: Thanks, even I (as current package maintainer of aptitude) wasn't aware of that "easter egg". :-D I'd though get a different message for each verbosity setting up to "6": See `aptitude -vvvvv moo` vs `aptitude -vvvvvv moo`. Additionally, more or less confirming shirish's findings, `aptitude -o Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose=<n> moo` doesn't work, it always gives me `There are no Easter Eggs in this program.`.

Comment: @Axel ah yes, up to 6, indeed. `aptitude -o` ignores the setting for me too, but setting it in the configuration file works...

Comment: The latter definitely sounds like a (IMHO minor, but still a) bug. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

> `Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose "2";`
>
> […]
>
> `$ sudo aptitude update`
>
> But neither gave me any more output.

For me, there is *more* output (to be precise one more line at the end) with either your example config or an additional `-v`, for example in a pbuilder Debian sid chroot with aptitude 0.8.12-1:

```
# aptitude update
Hit http://debian.ethz.ch/debian sid InRelease

# aptitude -v update
Hit http://debian.ethz.ch/debian sid InRelease

Current status: 0 (+0) broken, 0 (+0) upgradable, 17358 (+0) new.
# echo 'Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose "2";' >> .aptitude/config
# aptitude update
Hit http://debian.ethz.ch/debian sid InRelease

Current status: 0 (+0) broken, 0 (+0) upgradable, 17358 (+0) new.
#
```

Please note that with increased verbosity, aptitude also outputs package statistic differences.

However, this seems to be a bug, as aptitude is expected to output these statistics, too, but doesn't:

```
# aptitude -o Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose=2 update
Hit http://debian.ethz.ch/debian sid InRelease

#
```

[I reported this as bug to Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/946458). Thanks for bringing up this topic.

JFTR: I can also reproduce this (only tested `-v` vs `-o Aptitude::CmdLine::Verbose=2`) on Debian 10 Buster with aptitude 0.8.11-7, on Debian 9 Stretch with aptitude 0.8.7-1, and Debian 8 Jessie with aptitude 0.6.11-1+b1.